# can not create bean of .properties file in aop springframework

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, properties-file

I am using aop springframework.

```
<bean id="appProps" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="location" value="file:props\application.properties" /> </bean> 

 <!-- Transaction manager -->
<bean id="TransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- Transactional advice definition -->    
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="TransactionManager">
    <!-- the transactional semantics... -->
    <tx:attributes>

        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
<aop:pointcut id="svc" expression="execution(* com.example.dao.impl.DatabaseImpl.*(..))" />
<aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="svc" />
</aop:config>
```

But by using this I m getting error while creating bean appProps

I am using properties file in my code

Giving error can not create bean expected raw type not PropertiesFactoryBean

Stack trace as follows :

```
[SpringOsgiExtenderThread-72]|ERROR|org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.activator.ContextLoaderListener|104-org.springframework.osgi.extender-1.2.1|Application context refresh failed (OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext(bundle=com.example.deletion, config=osgibundle:/META-INF/spring/*.xml))
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'caseDeletionUtility' defined in URL [bundle://367.6:0/META-INF/spring/module-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'appProps' while setting bean property 'appProps'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appProps' defined in URL [bundle://367.6:0/META-INF/spring/module-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expecting raw type, not: org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)[12:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)[12:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)[12:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)[12:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)[12:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)[12:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)[12:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)[12:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)[12:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)[12:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)[12:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)[15:org.springframework.context:3.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$1600(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:69)[19:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
 at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:355)[19:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
 at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)[19:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
 at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:320)[19:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
 at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:132)[104:org.springframework.osgi.extender:1.2.1]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)[:1.7.0_17]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appProps' defined in URL [bundle://367.6:0/META-INF/spring/module-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expecting raw type, not: org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)[12:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)[12:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)[12:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)[12:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)[12:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)[12:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)[12:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
 ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expecting raw type, not: org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean
 at org.aspectj.weaver.TypeFactory.createParameterizedType(TypeFactory.java:37)[365:com.springsource.org.aspectj.weaver:1.6.8.RELEASE]
 at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.JavaLangTypeToResolvedTypeConverter.fromType(JavaLangTypeToResolvedTypeConverter.java:75)[365:com.springsource.org.aspectj.weaver:1.6.8.RELEASE]
 at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.JavaLangTypeToResolvedTypeConverter.fromTypes(JavaLangTypeToResolvedTypeConverter.java:123)[365:com.springsource.org.aspectj.weaver:1.6.8.RELEASE]
 at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.Java15ReflectionBasedReferenceTypeDelegate.getDeclaredInterfaces(Java15ReflectionBasedReferenceTypeDelegate.java:127)[365:com.springsource.org.aspectj.weaver:1.6.8.RELEASE]
 at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.getDeclaredInterfaces(ReferenceType.java:622)[365:com.springsource.org.aspectj.weaver:1.6.8.RELEASE]
 at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.getDirectSupertypes(ResolvedType.java:75)[365:com.springsource.org.aspectj.weaver:1.6.8.RELEASE]
 at org.aspectj.weaver.JoinPointSignatureIterator.findSignaturesFromSupertypes(JoinPointSignatureIterator.java:175)[365:com.springsource.org.aspectj.weaver:1.6.8.RELEASE]
 at org.aspectj.weaver.JoinPointSignatureIterator.hasNext(JoinPointSignatureIterator.java:68)[365:com.springsource.org.aspectj.weaver:1.6.8.RELEASE]
 at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.SignaturePattern.matches(SignaturePattern.java:316)[365:com.springsource.org.aspectj.weaver:1.6.8.RELEASE]
 at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.KindedPointcut.matchInternal(KindedPointcut.java:202)[365:com.springsource.org.aspectj.weaver:1.6.8.RELEASE]
 at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:134)[365:com.springsource.org.aspectj.weaver:1.6.8.RELEASE]
 at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.getShadowMatch(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:239)[365:com.springsource.org.aspectj.weaver:1.6.8.RELEASE]
 at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.matchesExecution(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:105)[365:com.springsource.org.aspectj.weaver:1.6.8.RELEASE]
 at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.matchesMethodExecution(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:96)[365:com.springsource.org.aspectj.weaver:1.6.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getShadowMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:403)[17:org..
```

Comment: Complete stack trace, please! Also, where do you use appProps bean?

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace, currently to little information. One thing use `/` instead of `\ ` in your `location` property.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I m using appProps for injecting in a bean

Comment: And how are you doing the injection? Can you show the code or configuration?